# SQL Server : converting varchar field to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in my table a `varchar` column with bunch of dates in the following format dd-MM-yyyy

```
31-12-2018
01-01-2019
02-01-2019
```

I need to write a date based query that gets all the dates before 01-01-2019. 
I have tried using both `CAST` and `CONVERT` to convert these table values without luck.

Using `CAST`, my code is below:

```
SELECT
    CAST('''' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 1, 2) + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 6, 5)+ '''' AS date), 
    CAST('''' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 7, 5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 4, 2) + '''' AS date),
    CAST('''' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 7, 5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date, 1, 2) + '''' AS DATE), 
    CONVERT(DATE, '12-31-2018') AS x 
FROM
    wkpol
```

Using Convert

```
select Convert(datetime,'''' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date,7,5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date,4,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(arc_billed_to_date,1,2)+ '''',105) as x from wkpol
```

The error I get is

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My question is why are storing dates in varchar. That is the point of the date(time) datatypes. You most likely have at least one row in your table with an invalid date. Depending on the version of sql server you might be able to use try_convert so you get NULL for those invalid rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM wkpol
WHERE convert(date, arc_billed_to_date, 103) < convert(date, '01/01/2019');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...I am accessing someone else's database and I knew I was going to get grief for this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Well you are going to get many blames for using varchar field for date. Anyway, assuming it is a matter of another thread you can do the conversion like:

```
select * from myTable
where cast(right(arc_billed_to_date,4) + 
substring(arc_billed_to_date,4,2) +
left(arc_billed_to_date,2) as date) < '20190101';
```

You wouldn't be using any index either.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sean's comments, you can also set the `DateFormat` as DMY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('31-12-2018')
,('01-01-2019')
,('02-01-2019')

Set DateFormat DMY

Select AsDate = try_convert(date,SomeCol)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
AsDate
2018-12-31
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
```